# foreach function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok my questions comes from an example from a book that i'm trying to understand.Keep in mind i just got into javascript.

So we have the object set and we define the function foreach. It takes another function as a parameter and invokes it for every item of an array "values" that belongs to set.

```
set.foreach = function(f,c) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.values.length; i++) 
        f.call(c,this.values[i]);
};
```

So far so good..

But i can't understand the usage of the foreach function in the second snipet.In particular i don't understand the role of the variable v. It is not defined enywhere else in the book and i m having a really hard time to understand how this work.We define another function in set to take the values as an array

```
set.toArray = function() {
    var a = [];
    this.foreach(function(v) { a.push(v); }); //where did v came from???
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I'm more surprised you didn't ask about the lack of the function names.  Parameters are pretty basic, but if you're getting this far, you're doing well in learning JS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
set.foreach = function(f,c) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.values.length; i++) 
        f.call(c,this.values[i]);
}; //                 ^-------------- being passed right here
```

The function you passed in is `f`, and `f` is invoked having the `this` value of its calling context set to `c`, and `this.values[i]` passed as the first argument.

```
       // ------v---------your function "f" in the forEach
this.foreach(function(v) { a.push(v); });
       // ------------^------references the first argument (after the "this" arg)
       //                      that was passed to "f"
```

---

Here's a simpler example:

This function accepts a function as a parameter. The only thing it does is call the function:

```
function my_func( fn ) {
    fn();
}

   // call my_func, which will call the function you give it
my_func( function() { alert( "hi" ); } );
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6a54b/1/

...so passing the function to `my_func` will alert the string "hi". No surprise.

---

But what if `my_func` provided the value to be alerted?

```
function my_func( fn ) {
    fn( "message from my_func" );  // call the fn passed, giving it an argument
}  //            ^------------------------------------------------|
   //                                                             |
   //               v------references the arg passed by my_func---|
my_func( function( arg ) { alert( arg ); } );
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6a54b/

Now you can see that an argument is being passed to the function we're sending over, and we reference that argument with the `arg` parameter.

It alerts whatever `my_func` gave it.

---

We can even take it one step further, by passing a second argument to `my_func` that `my_func` will simply take and pass it to the function we pass in.

```
function my_func( fn, str ) {
    fn( str );  // call the fn passed, giving it
}                                  //    the string we passed in

   //               v------the arg we passed here-----v
my_func( function( arg ) { alert( arg ); }, "I'm getting dizzy!" );
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6a54b/2/

And you can see that both arguments are given to `my_func`, and `my_func` calls the function we passed in, passing it the string argument we gave it.

Comment: Thanks @alex. Looks like someone disagrees with you. :o)

Comment: @TAL: `arg` is the defined as the parameter to the function. Its value is assigned by the `"message from my_func"` string that `my_func` is passing to it.

Comment: Patrick - "setting c to the this value in the calling context" is not correct. The *call* method sets the *this* value of the **called** function (i.e. *f*'s this, not *foreach*'s this). It is not *c* that is being set but *f*'s this. No value is passed anyway to *f*'s this resolves to the global object or null (depending on ES5 strict or other code).

Comment: @TAL: You've got to realize that the `function` is an Object that can be passed around. When we pass the function object to `my_func`, it can invoke that function, and pass whatever arguments it wants to it. The function will then be executed with whatever arguments it was given (if any).

Comment: @RobG: Yes, that's the calling context I was referring to. The context of `f` which is being invoked. I'll clarify. I could have said *"having its calling context set"* instead.

Comment: @alex: Redemption at last!  ;o)

Comment: thanks a lot guys.I will try to digest all this for the next couple of hours..!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `v`is an argument being passed to the function. It allows you to work with whatever the function receives. It is no different than `name`in the following example:

```
function sayHello(name) {
  console.log('Hello '+name);
}
```

Comment: yes but the outer function takes no arguments at all. How is it possible for the inner function to take arguments?

Comment: @TAL The "inner" function is being given arguments by the `foreach` function - `foreach` is the function that calls it, and the only one that can give it arguments, not the "outer" (`toArray`) function.

Comment: the outer function takes an argument, of sorts, the set itself which is referred to as `this`.  so `setA.foreach(...)` is different than `setB.foreach(...)` because inside the `foreach` function, `this` will refer to `setA` or `setB`

Answer (score 1):

f.call mean calling function `f` with arguments `this.values[i]`. `this` in foreach is set.
about calling `foreach` from `toArray`, passing function with `v`, the `values[i] in foreach` become `v in toArray`.

Answer (score 0):

`v` represents each item in the list as your `foreach()` function loops through them.

so if you have 10 items in your "set" the function will be called 10 times, providing each item in the set to the function as argument `v`

for example:

```
set = [1,2,3,4,5];

set.foreach = function(fn, context) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.values.length; i++) {
    fn.call(context, this.values[i]);
  }
};

set_times_2 = [];
set.foreach(function(item) {
  set_times_2.push(item);
  set_times_2.push(item);
});

// this is true now:
set_times_2 == [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5];
```

Answer (score 0):

`v` in this case is being passed in from the call statement `f.call(c, this.values[i])`.  Specifically, it is `this.values[i]`

The above statement is equivalent to simply:

```
f(this.values[i])
```

where `f` is the function in your 2nd snippet (`function(v){ a.push(v); });`)

The reason it's typed as `.call` instead of just calling it is so that the `this` property can be set, so `this` in your 2nd function is the array itself, meaning you could type:

```
function(v){
   alert(this.length); // "this" == array
}
```

Comment: That's a little confusing. In `set.toArray`, no value is passed to the *c* parameter of *foreach*, therefore when the function is called, *c* will be undefined so the function's *this* will be set to the global object (except in ES5 strict where it will be `null`). But that doesn't matter since *this* isn't used by the function. This is a really inefficient *toArray* function, I guess it's an example only.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers, here's one that specific to your question.

```
> this.foreach(function(v) { a.push(v); }); //where did v came from???
```

In the function expression passed to *foreach*, *v* is a formal parameter. Including an identifier as a formal parameter is more or less equivalent to declaring it in the function body with *var*. Maybe it's clearer if written as:

```
this.foreach( function (v) {
    a.push(v);
});
```

or not...